# how to dynamically name element in a lua table

Tags: lua

I have the following test code:

```
local luatable = {}
luatable.item1 = 'abc'
luatable.item2 = 'def'
```

I'd like to know how to change it so that I can dynamically assign the names becuase I don't know how many "items" I have. I'd like to do something like this: 
(pseudo code)

```
n = #someothertable
local luatable = {}

for i = 1, n do
  luatable.item..i = some value...
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to do something like this: `luatable.item..i = value`

That would be

```
luatable['item'..i] = value
```

Because `table.name` is a special case shorthand for the more general indexing syntax `table['name']`.

However, you should be aware that Lua table indexes can be of *any* type, including numbers, so in your situation you most likely just want:

```
luatable[i] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the correct code is

```
for i = 1, n do
  luatable["item"..i] = some value...
end
```

Recall that `luatable.item1` is just sugar for `luatable["item1"]`.